# Transferring from Domestic terminal T1B to International terminal T2 with luggage - Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, mumbai, bom

We will be arriving at the domestic Terminal 1B and need to transfer to the International Terminal 2.

We are a family of 4 with 8 pieces of checked luggage and four carry-on bags. Will there be big enough vans available?

We will be arriving around 4:30pm and our connecting international flight is at 10:20 PM. I haven't traveled through Mumbai airport in the last 10 yrs, so not sure about the current amenities.